# Rendering a list of json content fetched from an API via angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Angular newbie here, Trying to render a list of json content in the template. Using Angular 1.0.5.

Here is the app.js

```
var Task = angular.module("Task", ["ui.bootstrap", "ngCookies"]);

Task.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "static/js/app/views/todolist.html",
            controller: "TaskListController",
            resolve: {
                tasks: function (ToDoService) {
                    return ToDoService.list();
                }
            }
        })
........
```

Here is the TaskListController:

```
Task.controller('TaskListController', function ($scope, GlobalService, ToDoService, tasks) {
    $scope.tasks = tasks;
    console.log("tasks");**// this does not get logged. Any reason why?**
    $scope.globals = GlobalService;
});
```

ToDoService -

```
Task.factory('ToDoService', function ($http, $q) {
    var api_url = "/todo/";
    return {
        list: function () {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', url: api_url}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.reject(status);
                });
            return defer.promise;
        },
```

And the view goes here -

```
      <div class="content" ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        <a class="clip-open" href="{{task.api_url}}">
          <h3>{[{task.title}]}</h3>
        </a>
        <div class="meta clips-note">
          <p>
            {{task.description|truncate:150}}
          </p>
        </div>
        <p>
          <small><abbr time-ago title="{{post.assigned_time}}" class="date"></abbr></small>
          <small><b>by</b> {{task.kreator}}</small>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The server at /todo/ is returning a list of todos in JSON format. But in my browser, I can't see the data. What am I missing?

Please ignore all missing semi-colons and missing parenthesis. 
Assume all the files have been imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your resolve is "todos"

```
resolve: {
    todos: function (ToDoService) {
          return ToDoService.list();
    }
}
```

However, you are injecting `tasks` into your controller (which I don't see defined):

```
Task.controller('TaskListController', function ($scope, GlobalService, ToDoService, tasks) {
    $scope.tasks = tasks;
    $scope.globals = GlobalService;
});
```

I think you need to inject `todos` into your controller to access them.

Comment: yep figured it out. Thanks for the quick answer.